# Skip a PHP Variable (that is itself an Array) when Cycling through an Array with "foreach"

Tags: php, arrays

**Update**: It appears, upon further experimentation, that the problem is with $val. It may have been more helpful at describing the problem had I copied the full text of the error message: "*Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could **not be converted to string** in ...*". Evidently, PHP (for some reason) can't convert $val to a string. Note that the error message states that it is a catchable error.  I had hoped that the use of the "*continue*" parameter would bypass this error.

The code below works provided that none of the variables are themselves an array.

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val)
    {echo $key. ": ".$val. "<br>";}
```

Through experimentation, I figured out which "$key" was itself an array. Since I figured out which variable was causing the problem, the easy solution was simply to unset it. But that is not a good solution.

```
unset($_SESSION['issuenum_index']);
```

To get around the error, I attempted to use the "*continue*" statement. It did not work. See the code below.

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val)
            {if(is_array($key)) continue;    
                {echo $key. ": ".$val. "<br>";}}
```

How can the code above be revised to skip a variable when it is an array without triggering an error message?

**Update continued:** The "*foreach*" code failed and generated the following messages when the iteration reached the $key index "*issuenum_index*". Note that this "*foreach*" code correctly identifies the "$*key*" index as "*issuenum_index*" but hangs at this part of the code: "*var_dump($val);*"

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val)

            { var_dump($key);
                var_dump($val);
                echo "<br>";
            }
```

"*Warning: var_dump(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_result in ...*"

*Warning: var_dump(): Property access is not allowed yet in /var/www/sfmags/testform.inc.php on line 60
object(mysqli_result)#1 (5) { ["current_field"]=> NULL ["field_count"]=> NULL ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> NULL ["type"]=> NULL } *

Comment: @HoboSapiens: Except it is `$val` and not `$key`.

Comment: Thanks. Looked promising, but did not work.

Comment: First, array keys: [The key can either be an integer or a string.](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). The issue you are having, with regards, to _`$val`_ is that  it can be **anything**. For it to be 'displayed sensibly by _`echo`_ then it must: 1) Be known by PHP as something it can display as a string or 2) Know how to display itself as a string. I currently have no idea why _`var_dump($val)`_ in the _`foreach`_ hangs. However, i would like to see the surrounding code.

Comment: What's this question about?

Comment: @Ryan. Thanks for responding, I will post some more code soon.

Comment: @u_mulder. This post is about skipping a value that throws an error.

Comment: @Ryan. The short answer for why $val hung is that it turned out to be an object, not a value like integer or string. $_SESSION['issuenum_index'] is an array containing all the issue numbers for a magazine. The query for developing that is: $query = "Select IssueIDNUM,MagazineNUM FROM tblIssueList";    <br/>  $_SESSION['issuenum_index'] =$conn->query($query);     <br/>  This is also a mysqli connection, so maybe the array, in this case, constitutes an object, which I did not realize. As I lean more, I will have this figured-out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution that answers the question as posted. Essentially the variable $val associated with ($_SESSION['issuenum_index']) is an **OBJECT**.

In reading up on this, I found the following code snippet, that I applied to my case.

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $value) {
            echo gettype($value), "\n";
            }
```

The result: "*integer string **object** integer integer integer integer*". Which disclosed that one of my elements was an "*object*". The third element is the variable: $_SESSION['issuenum_index'].

I revised the original code to add "*not object*".

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val)
            if(!is_object($val))   
                { 
                    echo $key. ": ".$val. "<br>";   
                        } else {
                    echo "$key is an object <br>";
                  }
```

The code worked. I also revised the code to identify (echo) that "*$_SESSION['issuenum_index']*" was an object. This revision provides me a list of all my $_Session variables. My understanding of how this all goes together is still incomplete. I don't know why it works with $val? But that is another question.

$key, at one point in cycling through "$_SESSION" stands for "*issuenum_index*"
$val, I believed represented a value, such as "1". However, it is reported as being an "*object*". While this question is solved, I will still need to learn more.

Comment: Glad you investigated the PHP information to find your answer. I think the online PHP manuals and explanations make it so useful.